# Cannot update/download dependencies of Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to build [this project](https://github.com/PTC-ALM/integrity-plugin) in my eclipse. For this, I installed m2eclipse, and now I apparently need to update the dependencies via Maven.

Unfortunately, the "Update dependencies" doesn't run through. It just givesme this error in the projects `pom.xml` file:

```
Project build error:
Non-readable POM
C:\Users\flopes\.m2\repository\org\jenkins-ci\plugins\plugin\1.609.1\plugin-1.609.1.pom:
C:\Users\flopes\.m2\repository\org\jenkins-ci\plugins\plugin\1.609.1\plugin-1.609.1.pom
(System cannot find the file)
pom.xml
```

What is going on here? I looked into the referenced folder and these are the files present in there:

```
_maven.repositories
plugin-1.609.1.pom.ahc94dc028e8dc945b5
plugin-1.609.1.pom.ahcc7fe86ac64124fe0
plugin-1.609.1.pom.lastUpdated
```

*Side note: I have never worked with Maven before, so please don't assume any knowledge thereof when answering.*

**[pom.xml](https://github.com/PTC-ALM/integrity-plugin/blob/master/pom.xml)**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.609.1</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>integrity-plugin</artifactId>
    <name>PTC Integrity CM - Jenkins Plugin</name>
    <version>1.37-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>hpi</packaging>

    <url>http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PTC+Integrity+Plugin</url>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>ALM_JenkinsPlugin_Support</id>
            <name>PTC ALM Jenkins Plugin Support Team</name>
            <email>ALM_JenkinsPlugin_Support@ptc.com</email>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:ssh://github.com/jenkinsci/integrity-plugin.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/jenkinsci/integrity-plugin.git </developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.com/jenkinsci/integrity-plugin</url>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>workflow-scm-step</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.12.1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mks.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>mksapi-jar</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.5479</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>maven.jenkins-ci.org</id>
            <url>http://maven.jenkins-ci.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-hpi-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <compatibleSinceVersion>1.29</compatibleSinceVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
            <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
            <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

**Things I have done**

- Remove entire .m2 folder
- Download entire project new
- Import new project again in eclipse

New error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Updating indexes".
    org/eclipse/core/runtime/internal/adaptor/BasicLocation
```

- Old error persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a corrupt m2 folder. What you should do is:

1. Close eclipse.
2. open up your m2 folder and delete the contents inside. (make a back up first in another location)
3. Remove the current project files.
4. Re-download a clean copy.
5. Open up eclipse. Upon the boot, eclipse will download its necessary dependencies for maven. Let it download everything at 100%.
   During the download, it will look like this:
   [image]
6. Once it is completed, import your project. After importing is done, maven will start building the work space again. Let it finish.

   [image]

   7. Afterwards, right click on your project **Maven->Update Project** . This will trigger maven to download the required dependencies written in the pom.xml.

I tested the project out and it updates perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for the walkthrought. I followed it, but now a new error pops up in eclipse startup: `An internal error occurred during: "Updating indexes". org/eclipse/core/runtime/internal/adaptor/BasicLocation`

Comment: check if the option at 'Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Download repository updates index on startup' is enabled. Disable it and see if it resolves out of memory issue.